# output/echo a meesage in hql/ hive query language

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to create a hive.hql as follows.

HIVE.hql:

```
select * from tabel1;
select * from table2;
```

My question is: can i echo any message to my console like " results from table1 is obtained " in the hql code after table one is created like

```
select * from tabel1;
echo/print/output ("table 1 results obtained");
select * from table2;
```

Answer (score 20):

In the *.hql file insert a line as below in between the two hive queries.

```
!echo "table 1 results obtained";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a comment by editing your HIVE.hql :

```
select * from tabel1;
!sh echo "table 1 results obtained";
select * from table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

In beeline just use the below

```
--add your comment after 2 hypens and its printed in the console
```

Other solutions didnt work probably they are removed in current version